# Отобразить прямоугольник в массиве С++

Tags: c++

Есть карта

```
char** map(int n, int x, int y, int a, int b){

char** map = new char*[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    map[i] = new char[n];
}

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        map[i][j] = '-';
    }
}

return map;    }
```

теперь нужно отобразить на карте дав начальную точку x,y, ширину a и длину b прямоугольника

```
int main(){


int n = 15;
char** mapArr = map(n, 7, 7, 7, 9);


for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        cout << mapArr[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

}
и отобразить. Пробовал по обычному методу  [от сюда](http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread1647334.html)
но дав циклу начальную точку не смог отобразить возможно это так и не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то нужно просто добавить условие в функцию `map`:

```
char** map(int n, int x, int y, int a, int b)
{
    char** map = new char*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        map[i] = new char[n];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (i >= y && i < y + b && j >= x && j < x + a)
            {
                map[i][j] = '*';
            }
            else
            {
                map[i][j] = '-';
            }
        }
    }

    return map;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Если нужно вывести только рамку прямоугольника, то можно прописать условия для каждой стороны:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        if ((i >= y && i < y + b && j == x) ||
            (i >= y && i < y + b && j == x + a - 1) ||
            (j > x && j < x + a && i == y) ||
            (j > x && j < x + a && i == y + b - 1))
        {
            map[i][j] = '*';
        }
        else
        {
            map[i][j] = '-';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо! уже шел к такому решению

Comment: а как быть если нужен не полностью (закрашенный) а только стороны ?

Comment: @Rai, обновил ответ.